# Move positions in a table - R

Tags: r, matrix

In R, considering a generic matrix A, how can I move the triangle NA to the position in matrix B? What about if the matrix is m x n?

```
> A <- matrix(c(3, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, 1, 5, 3), nrow = 3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]   NA    2    5
[3,]   NA   NA    3


> B <- matrix(c(3, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 1, NA, NA), nrow = 3)
> B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]    2    5   NA
[3,]    3   NA   NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the mathematical interpretation of such transformation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if there's a more idiomatic way, but this seems to do what you want:

```
A <- matrix(c(3, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, 1, 5, 3), nrow = 3)
A

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]   NA    2    5
[3,]   NA   NA    3

t(apply(A, 1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]    2    5   NA
[3,]    3   NA   NA

A <- matrix(c(3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, NA, 1, 5, 3, NA), nrow=4)
A

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]   NA    2    5
[3,]   NA   NA    3
[4,]   NA   NA   NA


t(apply(A, 1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]    2    5   NA
[3,]    3   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA

A <- matrix(c(3, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, 1, 5, 3, 6, 7, 8), nrow=3)
A

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    4    1    6
[2,]   NA    2    5    7
[3,]   NA   NA    3    8

t(apply(A, 1, function(x) x[order(is.na(x))]))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    4    1    6
[2,]    2    5    7   NA
[3,]    3    8   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is to rotate 180 over columns. I assumed that the NA triangle from A is used to set NA in matrix B after rotation. One can use the same technique to rotate in A matrix itself.

```
A <- matrix(c(3, NA, NA, 4, 2, NA, 1, 5, 3), nrow = 3)
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]   NA    2    5
[3,]   NA   NA    3

B <- matrix(c(3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 6, 8), nrow = 3)
B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]    2    5    6
[3,]    3    4    8

#Find NA in A
NA_Val <- is.na(A)

#Rotate NA matrix on column
NA_VAL_180 <- NA_Val[1:nrow(NA_Val),ncol(NA_Val):1]

#Set corresponding values NA in B. 
B[NA_VAL_180] <- NA
B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    1
[2,]    2    5   NA
[3,]    3   NA   NA
```

Comment: How do you produce B in your first step in a more general sense? E.g. What if `A <- matrix(sample(c(NA,rnorm(9, 5, 1)), 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.3,rep(9/70, 9))), nrow = 10)`.

Comment: @JosephWood  OP has used 2 separate matrices and expressed intention to move NA triangle from A to B with rotation. This suggests he has a way to have both A & B before analysis.

Comment: I think the OP is asking to produce matrix B from A,... not sure though

Comment: @JosephWood but example provided him suggests differently. Isn't it?

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, I'm not really sure as the OP isn't very clear on this point. Maybe some clarification from the OP is in order. Regardless your approach is nice.